# Cliente e Servidor socket com Indy

Tags: delphi, socket, indy-10

Caros,
estou tentando criar um programa que vai receber uma lista de produtos vendidos, através de uma conexão Socket.
Consigo conectar via TCPClient, porém não estou conseguindo enviar a lista de comandos, e nem receber o resultado que vem do server.
No meu teste, consigo receber uma linha, mas preciso receber várias linhas.
Estou fazendo assim:

```
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LLine : string;
begin
  try
    if not IdTCPClient1.Connected then
      IdTCPClient1.Connect;

    IdTCPClient1.SendCmd(Edit3.Text);

    //LLine := IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadLn();
    Lline := IdTCPClient1.Socket.ReadString(6000);
    mmLog.Lines.Add(LLine);

  except
  on E:Exception do
      if ( E.Message <> 'Connection Closed Gracefully.') then
        mmLog.Lines.Insert(0, 'ERROR: ' + E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

Estou usando Indy 10 e Delphi Tokio.

Answer (score 0):

Prefiro utilizar o componente socket padrão, mas para `TIndy` já utilizei da seguinte maneira:

Considerando que o servidor escreva linha a linha, basta informar na primeira linha a quantidade de linhas que esta sendo enviada.

```
procedure TFormulario.IdServidor1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('3');
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('MENSAGEM 1');
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('MENSAGEM 2');
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('MENSAGEM 3');
end;
```

Agora imagine que no cliente você já possui a solução. Ou seja, ao invés de utilizar  `ReadString` utilize o `ReadStrings` que lhe devolvera uma lista de mensagens:

```
var
  i: Integer;
  vTexto: TStringList;
  vTamanho: Integer;
begin
  vTexto := TStringList.Create;

  vTamanho := IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadLn.ToInteger;
  IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadStrings(vTexto, vTamanho);

  for i := 0 to Pred(vTexto.Count) do
    Memo1.Lines.Add(vTexto[i]);
...
```

Neste caso, cabe uma pequena modificação no lado do Servidor para que ele sempre informe a quantidade de mensagens que esta enviando no pacote.

Comment: Entendi a ideia... O problema é que congela quando chama a linha: vTamanho := IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadLn.ToInteger;

Comment: O que esta enviando em `AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('3');` ?